# Number of $3$-colourings of this chain of $3$ triangles and $2$ trapeziums

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

> Each of the nine dots in this figure is to be colored red, white or blue. No two dots connected by a segment (with no other dots between) may be the same color. How many ways are there to color the dots of this figure?

[image]

Ok, so for the left thre dots, there are $3\cdot2\cdot1$ ways to connect them. Thus, our solution is $3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot3=18.$ I think I am missing something here, thank you in advance!

Comment: I got $54$ was to color them.

Comment: Hmm, will you please explain your process? :)

Comment: It's hard to discuss without some way of referring to the individual points.  Is it possible for you to label the points in the diagram?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to label the points on the diagram. I'm not very fluent with that.

Comment: I'll try to make one and add it to the question.  Or maybe I'll put it in an answer.  It will take me some time though.  I'm awfully slow at this kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you for all the help :)

Comment: @saulspatz like [this](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/zcqqupwd)? (image [here](https://i.imgur.com/9Ji0I0B.png)) (to FrostBite: and python count of $54$ is [here](https://tio.run/##RY47DsIwEER7n2I729KCYudLkZNEFBFKxOZjW/ZSwOVDCBJMM1PM6E148t27vAlx22gNPjIQD5G9X5K4tWlgNUb/GtwnrX1Q5BhJaxh9BAJyIKSxaHMsDJYGixLLCiuLtcWqxrrBJsdLjs1FnlNYiJVEqQUc0iIdhB/xHIa4Prhn8i4pmWWZMcZaK7UWIe5odSzTY1Xm/yABjeA8Q@@eirrpZK5tS928@1GacP7UbvrL1dv2Bg))

Comment: @saulspatz: I was about to post an answer, but I see that you were possibly preparing an answer. If so, I'll defer to you.

Comment: @quasi Yes, I'm in the middle of it.  I'm a terribly slow typist.

Comment: @saulspatz: No rush, I'll hold off.

Comment: Where you say "ways to connect them" (below the figure), do you mean ways to *color* them?

Comment: More generally, the chromatic polynomial turns out to be $x(x-1)(x - 2)^3 (x^2 - 3 x + 3)^2$, which yields $54$ for $x=3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've made a labeled diagram.
[image]
To make thing show up better I'm using red, green and blue as the colors.  Black vertices haven't been colored yet.  If we color $\triangle ABC$ as shown, then E must be colored green or blue and $D$ must me colored blue or red. Because of this, the color assigned to $F$ uniquely determines the coloring of $\triangle DEF$.  Now the same argument shows that however we color $\triangle DEF$, we have three choices for $\triangle GHI$.  Of course, there are six ways to color $\triangle ABC$, giving $6\cdot3\cdot3=54$ ways in all.

Comment: That's elegant. I was considering $(A,C)\to(D,E)$ in $3$ ways because $A\ne D$ and $C\ne E$ (left $2$ ways for $A$ and $2$ ones for $E$), but $D\ne E$ is $1$ more way less.

Comment: Nice (+1). I'm glad I waited. The argument I would have posted is slightly different than yours, but not better, and mine had no diagram.

Comment: @quasi, I wonder if your unposted argument is the same as mine (which also lacks a diagram). Should I delete?

Comment: @Barry Cipra: Your argument is nice (+1). Please don't delete it.

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same as saulspatz's answer (which I didn't read carefully until after posting), just viewed and presented slightly differently.

Color the three points of the *middle* triangle Red, White, and Blue, which can be done in any of $6$ ways, then look to color the points of the triangles to its left and right. For each of these, the color of the vertex of the middle triangle furthest away can be used in any of the $3$ positions, but as soon as it is, the colors of the other two vertices are determined by the constraint. As a result, the total number of colorings is

$$6\cdot3^2=54$$

Remark: The only (small) advantage this has over saulspatz's answer is that its symmetry makes it clear from the get-go that the answer will be of the form $6n^2$, where $n$ counts the ways to color the triangles to left and right.

Comment: Yes, the instant symmetry after coloring the middle triangle makes that choice very natural. I also like your choice of "farthest vertex" in the continuation. All in all, a clear, elegant presentation.